# check substrings in a string in java script

Tags: javascript, string

i want to check particular character occurrence in a string java script, 
following is what i need

- if the string having only one dot(.) between the string i have to alert `it is a object`
    eg: `var text = 'ABC.DEF';`
- if the string having open and closing brackets `()` at the very end
  of the string i have to alert `it is a function`
   eg: `var text = 'ABC()';`

i tried this

```
if(text .indexOf('()') === -1)
{
  alert("not function");
}
```

but how i can check whether brackets are in very end.

Comment: That is just JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: What if I have `foo.bar()`? Or `foo.position().top`?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer how? some demo??

Comment: Let me iterate that again: What if *the string* has both `.` and `()`? Where does it belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `^\w+\.\w+$` will match a string consisting of:

- the start of the string;
- a sequence of "word" characters;
- followed by a full stop;
- then another sequence of "word" characters; and
- finally, the end of the string.

Similarly, the regular expression `^\w+\(\)$` will match a string consisting of:

- the start of a string;
- a sequence of "word" characters;
- followed by open and closing round brackets; and
- finally, the end of the string.

You can wrap it in a function like this:

```
function check( text_to_match ){
    if(text_to_match.match(/^\w+\.\w+/)) 
        console.log("it is an object ");
    else if(text_to_match.match(/^\w+\(\)$/)) 
        console.log("it is an function");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You an use RegEx:

```
var one = "ABC.DEF";
var two = "ABC()";
var three = "()blank";

function check(string){

  // Matches: ABC.DEF  and Does not match: ABC. or .DEF
  if(/\w+\.\w+/.test(string)) 
    console.log("it is a function");

  // \(\) interpreted as (). Matches : ABC() ; Does not match: ()ABC or ABC()ABC
  else if(/\w+\(\)$/.test(string)) 
    console.log("it's an object");

  // Not found
  else
    console.log("something else")

}

check(one);    // it is a function
check(two);    // it's an object
check(three);  // something else
```

The `$` checks if the match(`()`) is at the end of the line.
The `\w+` is `count one or more occurrences of "A-Za-z0-9_"`.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sojamoxa/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 var a = "abc()";
        if (a[a.length-1] == ')' && a[a.length - 2] == '(') {
            alert("function");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/h9V2z/2/

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
   return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};

if("ABC()".indexOf("()") > -1) {
    alert("it is a function");
}

if("ABC.DEF".indexOf(".") > -1) {
    alert("it is an object");
}

if("ABC()".endsWith("()")=== true) {
    alert("ends with ()");
}

if("ABC()".endsWith("()whatever")=== true) {
    alert("ends with ()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1:

```
var s = "foo";
alert(s.indexOf("oo") != -1);
```

Comment: i want to know whether that character is in very end of the string or not

Comment: Indexof return the position of your substring. Just check if for example "(" return s.length - 1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if(text.substring(2) == "()")
  {
    alert("it is function");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) lets you use negative numbers to tackle the other end of the *String*.

```
'foobar'.slice(-2); // "ar"
```

so

```
if (text.slice(-2) === '()') {
    // last two digits were "()"
}
```